# Persistant Bottom Sheet Android

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

This is my code,

```
View bottomSheet = findViewById( R.id.bottom_sheet );
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(100);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(100);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

Is it possible to add overlay to background for Persistent Bottom sheet, when the Persistent bottom sheet is expanded?

Comment: you can add a listener to the bottom sheet behavior and set background depending on that

Answer (score 0):

If you want overlay bottom sheet, you can use bottom sheet dialog instead. With persistent bottom sheet, user can continue to work with main section of the screen. Where as with bottom sheet dialog, user can't work on the main section of the screen while dialog is on.